# Google Maps Android SDK - OnIndoorStateChangeListener issues

Tags: android, google-maps

I am displaying a map, which zooms onto a specific building. 
I want to be able to access the buildings floors and the current selected floor.

However, the code below does not work and I seem to have misunderstood the point of GoogleMap.OnIndoorStateChangeListener

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnIndoorStateChangeListener{

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    public void onIndoorBuildingFocused(){
        IndoorBuilding indoorBuilding = mMap.getFocusedBuilding();
        List<IndoorLevel> levels = indoorBuilding.getLevels();
        for (IndoorLevel indoorLevel : levels) {
            System.out.println(indoorLevel);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onIndoorLevelActivated(IndoorBuilding indoorBuilding) {
        List<IndoorLevel> levels = indoorBuilding.getLevels();
        for (IndoorLevel indoorLevel : levels) {
            System.out.println(indoorLevel);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        LatLng Location = new LatLng(51.501390, -2.548590);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Location, 18));

    }

}
```

How would I correctly return the building floors and current floor, for example when the selection in the default Google floor picker is changed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `getActiveLevelIndex()` under the public method `onIndoorLevelActivated(IndoorBuilding building)`.

Here's a sample code snippet:

```
googleMap.setOnIndoorStateChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnIndoorStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onIndoorBuildingFocused() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onIndoorLevelActivated(IndoorBuilding indoorBuilding) {
                List<IndoorLevel> levels = indoorBuilding.getLevels();
                int level = indoorBuilding.getActiveLevelIndex();
                Log.d("Tag", "Level Index: " + String.valueOf(level));
                String currentFloor = levels.get(level).getName();
                Log.d("Tag", "Level: " + currentFloor);
        }
    });
```

Note: The index(0) corresponds to the highest floor level. So if a building has for example 5 floor levels, the fifth floor level has an index of 0.

Comment: I see. Could I do this inside MapsActivity though? As I understand, the code you provided would be inside a separate class/file?

Comment: You can put this code inside ```public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {}``` on your Main Activity. Additional note: OnIndoorStateChangeListener() is a listener of your map object so you have add this listener to the map itself.

Comment: I have no way of testing this until later, so I will see what happens, thank you

Comment: This has in fact, solved my problem. Thank you very much for the explanation :)

Comment: Glad I was able to help with your issue. :)